# Weird behavior with lists with a derived generic type

Tags: c#, generics

So I have a list of a base type. This base type has two deriving classes, one of which is generic. I tried to foreach through the list and found this weird behavior.

```
public static void Test<T>()
{
    List<Base> myList = new List<Base>();

    myList.Add(new aDerived());
    myList.Add(new tDerived<T>());

    foreach (tDerived<T> lGen in myList as List<tDerived<T>>)
    {
        // This is fine
    }

    foreach (aDerived lDerived in myList as List<aDerived>)
    {
        // Error: Can't convert... via a reference conversion etc 
    }
}

//Simple classes to repro:
class Base
{

}

class aDerived : Base
{

}

class tDerived<T> : Base
{

}
```

This reports error [CS0039](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s92a6fk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) If the type is specified, ie instead of having a parametric method I replace T with, say, int, I get the same error on the first loop too.

Question: why does this happen. I can't see anything inherently impossible, I could, after all, do the `as` on the returned type of each iteration. On the flip side, why does it work if the thing is a template class, it seems like that shouldn't help it work.

Comment: Are you certain that the code for the first loop--as written--compiles? As far as I can tell, it should not. However, neither one of these loops should actually WORK, even if they do compile.

Comment: Just tested and the first loop compiles but it gives a run-time exception because the `as` expression evaluates to a null. I'm quite surprised it didn't give a compile time error like the second loop.

Comment: Yeah, probably should have run it, but couldn't run the code I spotted it in, so just tried to quickly get minimal code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is you are trying to convert a list of aDerived and tDerived into one or the other. This wont work as its like trying to convert a list of fruit (bananas and apples) into a list of apples. What you can do however is use the OfType extension to iterate over the items of the correct type:

```
foreach (tDerived<T> lGen in myList.OfType<tDerived<T>>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("tDerived found!");
}

foreach (aDerived lDerived in myList.OfType<aDerived>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("aDerived found!");
}
```

MSDN OfType: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I wanted it to and what I naively assumed the latter was doing.

Answer (score 2):

None of the below operations can be done. Not sure but as far as compiler is aware of `aDerived` type so it informs you that it cannot be done (compile time error). But in the second case the compiler has not enough information about the exact type of `tDerived<T>` (as it will be specified in runtime -because your method is a generic method), so it will not inform you. But when running the code it will throw exception.

```
var result1 = myList as List<aDerived>;     //Compile-time error
var result2 = myList as List<tDerived<T>>   //null
```

**More intersting:** This can be done with no compile time error:

```
List<Base> myList = new List<Base>();
var result = myList as List<T>;             //No Compile-time error
```

Also this link may be useful: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).